# Running NUnit test with thread principal set globally

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, nunit, integration-testing

I'd like to write some integration tests for view-models in my WPF solution, where threads' principal is set globally with 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(principal);`

NUnit doesn't provide mechanism to do the same from *test code*, with something like:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.NoPrincipal);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(myCustomPrincipalInstance);
```

It is possible to do it through NUnit's "Settings Dialog", but it is not what I need (more about this solution under [Test Loader Settings - Advanced / Principal Policy](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=settingsDialog&r=2.6.3).

Is there a way to run a test with globally set principal, so that it is available to all threads within code stack under test? Is there a NUnit plugin that can provide such functionality or is there a way to run a test with new AppDomain, to which I would be able to set custom principal (how would I do that)?

I tried to do something similar with MsTest where `PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal` is the default setting, but I was unable to set thread principal to AppDomain as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this thing in NUnit called [TestExecutionContext](http://nunit.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.5.10.11092plus-pdfsg-1/TestExecutionContext_8cs_source.html). You should be able to achieve the desired result by calling:

```
TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentPrincipal = customPrincipal;
```

Why this is so hard to find around the web, I have no idea, but unless you know it's there, it takes a while to get to it :-).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. For anyone else: I had to add reference to NUnit.Core, to get TestExecutionContext